# Mac address of a laptop by ip

Tags: mac-address

I lost my laptop and I do have ip address which recently accessed. Pls help anyone to trace my MAC address

Comment: You probably need to clarify what exactly your goal is, why would you need the MAC address?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the laptop is on your LAN, you can retrieve the MAC address like this

```
ping 10.0.0.5
arp -a 10.0.0.5
```

Where `10.0.0.5` is the IP address of your laptop. The ping is to add the IP to the ARP cache.

If the laptop isn't on your LAN, you can't get it's MAC address since the IP originates from a different source.

You can read more on how this works [here](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/Address-Resolution-Protocol-ARP)

Comment: one typically does not lose a laptop while plugged in to the LAN ...